# Django CSRF Token Missing Only in Production

Tags: ajax, django, forms, django-csrf

I am getting a missing CSRF_Token error that only occurs in production mode on my server.  However everything works great when I am running it from my computer terminal using the runserver command.  I've read through many of the other questions pertaining to this with no luck.  It seems that my case is slightly different than others, since it works locally but not in production.

I get the error when submitting an Ajax form that submits to the "submit" in views.py.  Does anybody know what could be causing this?  Also, looking at my cookies in Production mode, the CSRF_Token is not even there to begin with.  Locally it is.  Thanks for any help.

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):

    return render(request, 'index.html')


def submit(request):
    #Receive Request 
    inputone = request.POST['randominfo']
    inputtwo = request.POST['randominfo2']

    #Some more code here that setups response. 
    #Deleted since Im posting to StackOverflow

    return response
```

Code Pertaining to the Ajax Submit

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
    });
});

function getCookie(c_name)
{
    if (document.cookie.length > 0)
    {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1)
        {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
 }
function submitAjax(event){

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/submit/',
            data:{
                randominfo:document.getElementById('Random').innerHTML,
                randominfo2:document.getElementById('Random2').innerHTML,

            },
            dateType: 'json',
            success:function() {
                  # Url here  

            }

        })
    };
```

Solution that fixed this problem.

Adding "from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie" in views.py and then "@ensure_csrf_cookie" above the view that returns the html file that contained the ajax form

Comment: Why not just put `{% csrf_token %}` into your template directly instead of trying to get it out of cookies?

Comment: Thats one thing I have not tried.  Ill report back. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ocurs because you are not setting the csrf token, to prevent this we have to check some details

First of all, you have to set the csrf token to your form, in your html you have to set some as follow:

```
<form id="id" name="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!-- Form body here -->
</form>
```

Second the approach to set the csrf cookie to your request header is ok, i  only suggest that instead you set your data field one by one, use method `serialize` of jquery

`data: $("#your-form-id").serialize()`

I would like to recommend you to read this [post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) about ajax request with django that is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can do:

1.) Submit a CSRF token in your ajax call. You have to use a `getCookie()` javascript function to get it. Luckily the django documentation [has some code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) you can copy and paste.
javascript

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/submit/',
        data:{
            randominfo:document.getElementById('Random').innerHTML,
            randominfo2:document.getElementById('Random2').innerHTML,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': getCookie('csrftoken'), // add this
...
```

2.) Disable csrf for your /submit view. You can do this with a decorator. Note that this is less secure so make sure there's no confidential data.

views.py:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
...
@csrf_exempt
def your_submit_view(request):
  #view code
```

Comment: Disabling the CSRF token is not a good idea and should not be done under any circumstances.